# map function in tidyverse language

Tags: r, dictionary

I have the following formula

```
#Regression(Y1 - VTV)----
m1_vtv<-formula(vtv~retailsales)
m2_vtv<-formula(vtv~retailsales+cpi)
m3_vtv<-formula(vtv~retailsales+cpi+tmf)

#Regression(Y2 - VUG)----
m1_vug<-formula(vug~retailsales)
m2_vug<-formula(vug~retailsales+cpi)
m3_vug<-formula(vug~retailsales+cpi+tmf)
```

and I have added them into a list called regression_list

```
regression_list<-c(m1_vtv,m2_vtv,m3_vtv,m1_vug,m2_vug,m3_vug)
```

I am trying to glance() all the models in regression_list together.
Individually it works:

```
tidy(model1) %>% as_tibble()
glance(model1)
```

[image]

However when I tried this

```
regression_list %>% 
  map(~lm(.x, data = df_final)) %>%
   map(~as_tibble(.x, data = df_final)) %>% 
  map(~glance(.x, data = df_final))
```

I get error message:

> Error in as.data.frame.default(value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) :
> cannot coerce class ‘"lm"’ to a data.frame

Looking for way to fit this into map function to run through all the formulas in `regression_list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says you are trying to convert `lm` object to tibble. You also don't need multiple `map`'s as you can do this in the same `map` function. Try :

```
library(purrr)
library(broom)

result <- regression_list %>% map(~glance(lm(.x, data = df_final)))
```

If you want the `result` in one dataframe you can use `map_df` in place of `map`.